# Using Activity ViewModel in Fragment's Layout with Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, viewmodel, androidx

Trying to access an activities viewModel in a fragment's layout using data binding. I am not sure if I am just doing something wrong, or if it's something that just doesn't work.

The MainViewModel has a MutableLiveData property called _dateString, and a function called getDateString() that returns the LiveData of that property.

```
private val _dateString = MutableLiveData<String>()
fun getDateString(): LiveData<String> {
    return _dateString
}
```

That function is then called in the Calendar fragment's layout. I have both the mainModel and the viewModel in the data section of the layout. ( I stripped out most of the layout so its easier to read )

```
<layout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
            name="mainModel"
            type="{path}.features.main.MainViewModel" />
    <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="{path}.features.main.calendar.CalendarViewModel" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/header_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:text="@{mainModel.getDateString()}"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the fragment itself, I then bind the variables as such

```
binding = FragCalendarBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
        viewModel = model
        mainModel = mainModel
        listener = this@CalendarFragment
        lifecycleOwner = this@CalendarFragment
    }
```

For whatever reason, the layout shows the button without a value. Even if I update the _dateString, the binding doesn't display the changed string.

If I move the same logic into the CalendarViewModel, it does show up and update. If I call the getDateString() in the Calendar's fragment code, it returns the value correctly.

Are you just unable to have multiple view model's connected to a single layout? Or am I doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i am late for answering this question. anyways, just edit your XML file in this way

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/header_title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            android:text="@{mainModel._dateString}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your ViewModel data like this to eliminate the need for function calls:

```
private var _dateString = MutableLiveData<String>()
val dateString : LiveData<String>
    get() = _dateString
```

This allows you to access the value outside your ViewModel as `dateString` 
Then in your XML, you can now assign the value of your text to `@{mainmodel.dateString}` and the value will be updated automatically whenever it changes